# Overwrite local repo with Remote Repo

Tags: git

I have two remote Git repositories, "Framework" and "Client".

How our repositories work:

1. Create a Client repository
2. Add the Framework remote repository (Now there are two remotes, Client and Framework)
3. Pull the Framework repository into the Client repository
4. Changes are made to the Client files and pushed to the Client repository
5. Changes are made to the Framework files and then pushed to the Framework repository and then are pulled into the Client repository

Now my question is... when I pull the Framework repo into the Client, how can I guarantee the Framework files in the Client repo are overwritten so the are always exactly the same as Framework?

Example folder setup:

```
client_file.php
client_folder_1/
    client_file.php
framework_file.php
framework_folder_1/
    framework_file.php
```

When I pull Framework into Client, all the "framework_*" files and folders will be exactly what's in Framework, no matter what changes were made to them (if any) in the Client repo.

Comment: If you have two distinct and disjoint repositories, is there any reason that you're attempting to combine them into one?

Comment: @Makoto When we setup the Client website we can just pull their client repo

Comment: I suppose you need to make the relationship between Framework and Client a bit clearer.  Are they distinct and disjoint?  Does the Client repository absolutely need the Framework repository in order for it to function?

Comment: @Makoto Ah. I wouldn't say the Client repo needs the Framework repo to function, but the website needs to files from both.